# Часть переключателей MPC-HC не работает при создание процесса ProcessBuilder'м

Tags: java, io

Класс в котором формируется объект ProcessBuilder:

```
public class MpcRunner {
private String Mpc;
private String path;
private String displayNumber;
private String port;
private final String webport = "/webport ";
private final String monitor = "/monitor ";
private final String fullscreen = "/fullscreen";

public MpcRunner(String mpc, String path, String displayNumber, String port) {
    this.Mpc = mpc;
    this.path = path;
    this.displayNumber = displayNumber;
    this.port = port;
}

public String getPort() {
    return port;
}
public void run() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ProcessBuilder mpcProc = new ProcessBuilder(Mpc,path,monitor+displayNumber);
    Process process = mpcProc.start();
    process.waitFor();
}}
```

Вызываемый конструктор:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    MpcRunner mpcRunner = new MpcRunner("C:\\Program Files\\MPC-HC\\mpc-hc64.exe","C:\\video1.mp4","1","55555");
    mpcRunner.run();}
```

При попытке создать процесс с атрибутами /monitor и/или /webport mpc-hc[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**При переносе, составленной команды, в командную строку MPC-HC запускается корректно.**

> ### Media Player Classic — Home Cinema (64-bit)
>
> Build information:
>       Version:            1.7.10 (d911f14)
>       Compiler:           MSVC 2013 Update 5
>       Build date:         Nov 14 2015 18:25:24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, **все** переключатели необходимо передавать, как одну команду:

```
public void run() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ProcessBuilder mpcProc = new ProcessBuilder(Mpc,path+" "+monitor+displayNumber);
    Process process = mpcProc.start();
    process.waitFor();
}
```

С чем это связано я увы, так и не выяснил.